# MySQL query to retrieve either home phone or cell phone

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table that keep profiles of member.The table has `home_phone` and `cell_phone` fields as shown below

```
First_name  Last_name   Home_phone  Cell_phone
John        Smith       4161234567  
Michael     More                    6471234567
Judy        Doe         4164567896  
Lolita      Garcia                  6471478956
XXXXx       YYYYYY      416231478
ZZZZZ       KKKKKK      416785123
MMMMM       NNNNNN      416789456
XXXXX       PPPPP       416555253
```

I want to retrieve data as shown below:

```
First Name   Last Name   Phone Number
John         Smith       4161234567 
Michael      More        6471234567
Judy         Doe         4164567896 
Lolita       Garcia      6471478956
```

How I can write the SQL Query to achieve that?

Thanks so much.

Comment: And why don't you want the last four rows?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think these row are just dummy useless-one for this case, the point is about how to handle NULL ( with a simple coalesce indeed)

Comment: To clarify, can a person have no phone (and if so should they be returned by the SQL query)?  Also, can a person have *both* Home and Cell phones, and if so do you wish us to return a row for each or give preference to one phone type over another?

Answer (score 3):

[COALESCE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function :

```
SELECT 
    `First_Name`, 
    `Last_Name`, 
    COALESCE(`Home_phone`, `Cell_phone`) as `Phone_Number`
FROM `table`;
```

---

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/035f69/3)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t
    (`First_name` varchar(7), `Last_name` varchar(6), `Home_phone` varchar(10), `Cell_phone` varchar(10))
;

INSERT INTO t
    (`First_name`, `Last_name`, `Home_phone`, `Cell_phone`)
VALUES
    ('John', 'Smith', 4161234567, NULL),
    ('Michael', 'More', NULL, 6471234567),
    ('Judy', 'Doe', 4164567896, NULL),
    ('Lolita', 'Garcia', NULL, 6471478956),
    ('XXXXx', 'YYYYYY', 416231478, NULL),
    ('ZZZZZ', 'KKKKKK', 416785123, NULL),
    ('MMMMM', 'NNNNNN', 416789456, NULL),
    ('XXXXX', 'PPPPP', 416555253, NULL)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select * from t
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/035f69/3/0)**:

```
| First_name | Last_name | Home_phone | Cell_phone |
|------------|-----------|------------|------------|
|       John |     Smith | 4161234567 |     (null) |
|    Michael |      More |     (null) | 6471234567 |
|       Judy |       Doe | 4164567896 |     (null) |
|     Lolita |    Garcia |     (null) | 6471478956 |
|      XXXXx |    YYYYYY |  416231478 |     (null) |
|      ZZZZZ |    KKKKKK |  416785123 |     (null) |
|      MMMMM |    NNNNNN |  416789456 |     (null) |
|      XXXXX |     PPPPP |  416555253 |     (null) |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select 
    `First_Name`, 
    `Last_Name`, 
    COALESCE(`Home_phone`, `Cell_phone`) as `Phone_Number`
from t
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/035f69/3/1)**:

```
| First_name | Last_name | Phone_Number |
|------------|-----------|--------------|
|       John |     Smith |   4161234567 |
|    Michael |      More |   6471234567 |
|       Judy |       Doe |   4164567896 |
|     Lolita |    Garcia |   6471478956 |
|      XXXXx |    YYYYYY |    416231478 |
|      ZZZZZ |    KKKKKK |    416785123 |
|      MMMMM |    NNNNNN |    416789456 |
|      XXXXX |     PPPPP |    416555253 |
```

Comment: But what result this query will have if both columns are not null?

Comment: @VladimirKroz Coalesce `Returns the first non-NULL value in the list`, and this is starting from the left (reading order so) : `Coalesce(NULL, 'Returned as null before', 'never returned as not null before')`

Comment: @user1554459 you're welcome ! don't forget to set the answer as "solved my question" to close it (the green check under +1/-1 vote)